# Open Javascript code in editor on click

Tags: javascript, editor, html

I am trying to create an interactive tutorial for learning an API. I've been googling my options for an entire day now. I came across ace, code mirror etc. but I'm not sure how I can use them in my case. 
What I wish to do is that when the user clicks a button, a javascript code linked to it should open up in an editor on the same webpage. This would aid the users to see how the code is working and give them scope to modify and learn.
I know its not a constructive question but any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: CodeMirror's [`setValue`](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_content) should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used  tags to store my code and displayed it using codemirror's setValue property mentioned by @georg.

Answer (score 0):

you can just wantch [here how it is done](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/)

They made it with knockout MVVM but you can use angular or anything else you like.